# HTML TABLE to CSV converter

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to convert a simple (but big) HTML table to CSV in Java.

I have tried looking around for code, however am non the wiser. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be extremely grateful.

Here is the html table file i'm trying to convert:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Destination</th>
<th>Dial Code</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Currency</th>
<th>Next Change</th>
<th>New Rate</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afghanistan Mobile Afghan Telecom</td>
<td>9375</td>
<td>0.1829</td>
<td>USD</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afghanistan Mobile Awcc</td>
<td>9370</td>
<td>0.1777</td>
<td>USD</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afghanistan Mobile Etisalat</td>
<td>9378</td>
<td>0.1595</td>
<td>USD</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afghanistan Mobile Mtn (Afghanistan)</td>
<td>9376</td>
<td>0.191</td>
<td>USD</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
<td>----</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to do with Jsoup. You should parse every row and walk through every cell in that row, separating them by commas. Like this:

```
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("csv.txt");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(table);
        Elements rows = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements cells = row.getElementsByTag("td");
            for (Element cell : cells) {
                writer.write(cell.text().concat(", "));
            }
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly whip up something using regex, but a simpler approach would be using an HTML parser and going from there. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a good one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18848835/4339766) could be a good place to start from.

Answer (score 1):

You can done this from this simple code, no need to use any external libraries

```
public static ArrayList<String> readInCSVFormat(File htmlFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> data = FileUtil.readFile(htmlFile); //this method returns the html page line by line in ArrayList only
    outer: for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        String line = data.get(i).replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            if (line.matches("[0-9]+")) { //can be changeable as per the needs and optional
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    line = data.get(i).replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim();
                    if (line.isEmpty()) {
                        result.add(builder.toString().substring(0, builder.toString().lastIndexOf(',')));
                        continue outer;
                    }
                    builder.append(line).append(",");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract data from html and convert it to json then you can use following jsfiddle code to create csv from json.

```
[jsfiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/JXrwM/1801/ "Stack Overflow"
```